Creating streamlit-altair chart from example renders no data
I'm trying to render the streamlit-altair chart from this example, so I implemented the following code:
import altair as alt
import streamlit as st

from view.frontend.path import BasePath

chart_spec = {
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "description": "A bar chart with highlighting on hover and selecting on click. (Inspired by Tableau's interaction style.)",
    "data": {
        "values": [
            {"a": "A", "b": 28}, {"a": "B", "b": 55}, {"a": "C", "b": 43},
            {"a": "D", "b": 91}, {"a": "E", "b": 81}, {"a": "F", "b": 53},
            {"a": "G", "b": 19}, {"a": "H", "b": 87}, {"a": "I", "b": 52},
        ]
    },
    "params": [
        {
            "name": "highlight",
            "select": {"type": "point", "on": "pointerover"}
        },
        {"name": "select", "select": "point"}
    ],
    "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "fill": "#4C78A8",
        "stroke": "black",
        "cursor": "pointer",
    },
    "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal"},
        "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
        "fillOpacity": {
            "condition": {"param": "select", "value": 1},
            "value": 0.3,
        },
        "strokeWidth": {
            "condition": [
                {
                    "param": "select",
                    "empty": False,
                    "value": 2,
                },
                {
                    "param": "highlight",
                    "empty": False,
                    "value": 1,
                }
            ],
            "value": 0
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "scale": {"bandPaddingInner": 0.2}
    }
}

class Path(BasePath):
    def __init__(self, payload: dict):
        self._path_spec = payload

    def render(self, container):
        with container:
            # Altair Chart
            chart = alt.Chart().from_dict(chart_spec)

            # Display chart in Streamlit
            click_event = st.altair_chart(
                chart, use_container_width=True, on_select="rerun"
            )

            # Catch the click and display result
            if click_event is not None:
                st.write(f"Clicked on: {click_event}")

The problem is that I'm getting an empty chart in my app unlike the example page that is full with data.
What am I doing wrong?

The altair chart displays as expected without streamlit, so the issue is somewhere in the streamlit specific parts of the code. Maybe try making the example even more minimal to figure out where things go awry?
